# C# Express and .Net framework 4.5 - Backwards compatability

Tags: c#

I have just written a small C# app that I want to put on 4/5 PCs. The PCs have various OS's installed ranging from XP (with the latest SP supporting 4.5) to Win 8 SP1.  Each PC also has various apps running, which is where my question is.

I just wanted to check to see if there is anything I need to be mindful of in relation to older applications running earlier versions of .Net (in theory at least).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As long as they have the same .NET version as your app is targeting and you don't make any unmanged calls it should be fine.

Comment: What if they are running older versions of .Net?

Comment: Compile your program with .NET Framework you need. (Right click on Project => Properties => Target Framework). You may need to rewrite your code to fit to Framework

Comment: Take a look on which features that are included in .NET 4.5, are you using them? If not you could simply target an older version of .NET

Answer (score 1):

The later `.NET` versions contain features and APIs that older versions do not. For instance, `.NET 2` does not support `LINQ`, whereas `.NET 3.5` does.

It is also worth noting that according to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z6watww%28v=vs.110%29.aspx, `Windows XP SP3` does not support `.NET 4.5`